# XML Documentation Comments in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio (C#/VB.NET, not sure in other languages?), if you add three slashes at the top of a method or property, Visual Studio auto-creates a structured way giving information for the method and its parameters and return values, where applicable. It's useful for creating developer documentation, but mostly I use it to reference information about a method I'm calling if, for example, I have multiple overloads and need to see which one I'm calling. [See MS docs link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/).
Does VS Code have anything like that? I can't seem to find it in the key bindings in preferences. Maybe there's something similar in VS Code that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Single line comments don't produce the XML documentation but the following syntax does:

```
/**
   * include a description of your method to be viewed when you mouse over the method call
   */
```